# Broken unity / compiz on an ATI Mobility Radeon HD3650

Tags: unity, 11.10, compiz

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 x86_64, with graphic ATI Mobility Radeon HD3650

UNity doesn't start, but I still have unity 2D.

I tried `compiz --replace`

it gives me :

```
Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no

Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...no

Backend     : gconf

Integration : true

Profile     : default

Adding plugins

Skipping upgrade com.canonical.unity.unity.01.upgrade

Skipping upgrade com.canonical.unity.unity.02.upgrade

Initializing core options...done

...
...

Initializing fade options...done

Initializing scale options...done

Initializing session options...done

compiz (core) - Warn: no exact match for ConfigureNotify on 0x2e00092!

compiz (core) - Warn: expected the following changes:

compiz (core) - Warn: sibling: 0x43ee95

compiz (core) - Warn: instead got:

compiz (core) - Warn: x: 0

compiz (core) - Warn: y: 0

compiz (core) - Warn: width: 1440

compiz (core) - Warn: height: 900

compiz (core) - Warn: above: 0

compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
Setting Update "left_key"
Setting Update "right_key"
Setting Update "up_key"
Setting Update "down_key"
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I have a ATI Radeon Mobility X1400, and basically the same issues. I don't have a solution, but I switched to Gnome Shell (sudo apt-get install gnome-shell), it works as expected and without issues.

Comment: could you paste your output of `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` ?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11373928) worked for me:

> The Unity plugin box is not checked in CCSM by default. Login and
>   select unity 2d. Open CCSM and check the Unity plugin box. Log out and
>   back in with Unity selected.